# Как показать первые четыре елемента масива, не делая новый масив

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть массив примерно на 30 элементов, и мне нужно показать в один момент 4 элемента и когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "показать больше" ему показывается весь массив. Проблема заключается в следующем всё это реализовано через input type='radio' и когда я делаю маленький массив из 4 элементов с помощью slice - checked пропадает из раннее выбранного елемента.

Comment: На словах это хорошо, но увидеть бы по коду это.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно не все мне понятно, но можно воспользоваться деструктивным присваиванием по такому принципу.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

const [first, second, third, fourth, ...rest] = array; // разделить
const array2 = [first, second, third, fourth, ...rest]; // обьединить

console.log(first, second, third, fourth);    
console.log(rest);
console.log(array2);
```